# проблемы с .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

С интервалом в несколько дней сайт падает из-за ошибки 500 (Internal Server Error). Техподдержка подсказала, что причина в файле .htaccess в корневом каталоге сайта.

Обнаружил, что файл разрастается до невероятных размеров (1,5 мб) из-за того, что содержимое файла копируется много-много раз. После удаления лишнего кода, ситуация повторяется. Может кто-то помочь советом, что с этим делать?

Comment: По каким причинам в файл пишутся данные без, как я понял, вашего ведома?

Comment: меня тоже этот вопрос занимает, код копируется многократно..

Comment: Так дайте больше информации. Это CMS или самописный сайт?

Comment: сайт на WordPress

Comment: Насколько мне известно запись могут запрашивать сторонние плагины через встроенную функцию записи. Скорее всего, один из них записывает туда свою конфигурацию. Вам следовало бы приложить строки, которые дублируются. Или попробуйте отключить сторонние плагины.

Comment: дублируется все полностью, попробую отключить некоторые плагины, спасибо

Answer (score 2):

1) Зловред какой-то.

2) Плагин какой-то пишет. Многие плагины на кеширование это делают, чтобы статикой потом страницы отдавать.

Попробуйте отключить плагины и посмотрите будет ли повторяться. Попробуйте [секьюрные плагины](https://wordpress.org/plugins/tags/security).

Можно поставить права на .htaccess файл 444, чтоб исключить апдейты этого файла.

Comment: некоторые плагины отключил, попробую почитать про второй способ

Comment: @DmitriyPugach ну как, проблема решилась?